# How to use swagger with akka-http & basic auth

Tags: scala, swagger, akka-http, swagger-akka-http

I am trying to document an akka-http API using swagger & [swagger-akka-http](https://github.com/swagger-akka-http/swagger-akka-http). [This blog post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/04/swagger-akka-http/) gave me a good start, but now I am stuck, trying to document the fact that the API is using basic auth.

what I have is:

```
@Path("/foo")
@Api(value = "/foo", produces = "application/json")
class FooService ...

@ApiOperation(value = "Get list of all foos", nickname = "getAllFoos", httpMethod = "GET",
response = classOf[Foo], responseContainer = "Set")
def getAll: Route = get {...
```

This generates a json which I can view in the swagger UI. However, I cannot use the generated examples, as the auth option is missing.

I have not found any examples using swagger-akka-http, only some using `yaml` config

In a `yaml`, this could look like this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  basicAuth:
    type: basic
    description: HTTP Basic Authentication.
```

however, I do not have a `yaml`. Nor do I have control over the generated `.json` except through the annotations.

IIUC, the correct place to mention the auth method is the `authorizations` parameter of the `Api` or `ApiOperation` annotations. This param should contain an array of `Authorization` annotations.

The `value` attribute of each `Authorization` annotation is supposed to reference a [`SecurityDefinitionObject`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-definitions-object)

But I have no idea how to define this `SecurityDefinitionObject` using annotations.

The [`Authorization`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/Authorization.html) annotation is not supposed to be used standalone and is ignored if it is.

Is there something I have missed? Do I need an extra `yaml` or `json` file with additional declarations and where do I put it if I do? Something much more else?

Thank you

**EDIT**

With the 0.7.2-SNAPSHOT, the basicAuth array is being generated lie this:

```
paths: {
    /foos: {
        get: {
        security: [
            {
            basicAuth: [ ]
            }
        ],
```

Now the only issue is to get the Swagger UI to interpret it correctly and use the auth in the examples. AFAIK, if you need basic auth in the UI, you have to add it yourself, like it is described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/IziMnUwneKs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently maintain [swagger-akka-http](https://github.com/swagger-akka-http/swagger-akka-http).

The code is pretty much a thin wrapper around swagger.io code base.

The @Api and @ApiOperation annotations support an authorizations param.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-annotations/src/main/java/io/swagger/annotations/Api.java

```
@Api(value = "/myApi", description = "My API", produces = "application/json", 
authorizations=Array(new Authorization(value="basicAuth")))
```

I have never used this functionality but maybe you could try it out.

Comment: I think I see what you are seeing in that @Api authorizations value don't appear to come out the swagger json. I've looked at the io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader class and it looks like it might provide what is needed. I can investigate adding support like the existing Info object support on the SwaggerDocService class in swagger-akka-http.

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/swagger-akka-http-sample/tree/api-authorizations has a modification demoing an @Api annotation with an authorization and that does get output in the swagger json (http://localhost:12345/api-docs/swagger.json). `"security": [{
          "basicAuth": []
        }],`

Comment: I've created a 0.7.2-SNAPSHOT version of swagger-akka-http which supports setting security definitions - https://github.com/pjfanning/swagger-akka-http-sample/tree/security-definitions shows the usage in a sample

Comment: Many thanks, with the 0.7.2-SNAPSHOT it works. Swagger UI is not cooperating though. Will have to tweak the UI code.